# What are the two main genres that pitch bend drum hits?

Tags: drums

In the Netherlands or something when they use drums they often edit or synthesize each hit to accelerate downward in pitch and have an electronic timbre. It's a low pitched drum that sounds like daum daum daum daum daum daum a few quicker funky hits daum daum daum daum daum daum.  [Here's an example](https://youtu.be/fiwFnl0RErA?t=124).  **What is this genre called?**  (Most Jumpstyle doesn't pitch bend their beats so it's not Jumpstyle.)

Hispanic people seem to do the opposite - high pitched drums, bends them very differently generally up, the pitch changes quicker and moves more I think, and ends quicker, more funkiness, less repetition and no adding electronic timbres.
I don't have an example I can link to, I just see Latino drivers playing it.

Comment: Might be an idea to include a YouTube link to a track so we can hear the actual effect.

Comment: Why two genres? Why not three or four, or one?

Comment: Okay, there could be more but I've only heard two styles of bending the pitch of drums while they're still reverberating, the electronic music style and the Hispanic one and one of them is very popular in Mexico at least and the other's only popular in Europe so they have large fanbases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about the Latin American percussion style you're describing, but the four on the floor beat you mentioned from the Netherlands sounds a lot like the one from the [Gabber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabber) genre. In that case, it might also be less accelerating downward in pitch and more just distorting the pitch.